# how to call object of one class that has been created in another class?

Tags: java

I'm just starter at coding . I wanna write a game code and I have a problem :
I want to call an object of one class in another class but there is a eror with my code.

I have three classes : Game , Player , commandReader.

class Player :

```
public class Player{

   public void moveUp(){
   ...
   }
}
```

I had been created an object of class Player in Game class:

```
public class Game{

   public Player player;

   private Game(){
      player = new Player;
   }

   // methods omitted
}
```

I want to call object "player" in another class named commandReader :

```
public class commandReader{

   public readCommand(String command){
      if(command == "Up"){
         player.moveUp();
      }
   }
}
```

but there is a error when I run the code. the object player is unknown for class commandReader. I should mention that I don't wanna create another object of class Player in class commandReader and I just use the one that has been created in the Game class. 
how should I call that?

Comment: This code have compilation problems. Maybe you need a basic learning about programming.

public Player; // must be public Player player;

Comment: Your if-statement wont work. You have to compare `String`s using `.equals()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pass a reference to the game class into the constructor of commandReader.

```
Game game;

public commandReader(Game game)
{
    this.game = game;
}
```

And then you can call

```
game.player.moveUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some errors.

In the class Game you have to declare the variable player in that way:

```
public Player player;
```

Then in the constructor of the Game class

```
player = new Player();
```

Which can't be call because in the Player class there isn't the constructor

```
class Player{

  //CONSTRUCTOR (initialize the object)
  public Player(){

  }

  [...]

}
```

After that adjustment you can call the player from commandReader with

```
Game.player.moveUp();//Only if it's a static variable
```

Hope you understand something new.

[UPDATE]

Right you also don't add the constructor in the Game class, because it must be

```
public Game(){
  [...]
}
```

And not

```
private Game(){
  [...]
}
```

Then in the commandReader you have to create a Game object by

```
Game game = new Game();
```

And then for the player

```
game.player.moveUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

The commandReader class doesn't show a game object anywhere.

```
public class commandReader{

   Game myGame = new Game();
   public readCommand(String command){
      if(command == "Up"){
      myGame.player.moveUp();
  }
```

}
}